# the word order in as... as?

Tags: grammar, word-order

> getting all children off on the right foot is an often-stated goal of pre-K, but in many ways, creating equity is *as big a challenge as* building quality

would it be incorrect if I say:

> creating equity is *as a big challenge as* building quality

does the phrase put between as... as have a different word order when it has complements to the adjective or adverb in it?

Comment: The original construction *X is **as big a challenge as** Y* is fine, as would be *X is **as challenging as** Y*. Your alternative, with the indefinite article ***a*** coming *between* the word ***as*** and the relevant adjective *(**big**)* is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is what are wishing to express a "challenge" or a "big Challenge"?

I would suggest you are comparing the two Challenges "Equity" and "Quality"

In which case the sentence will be **"creating equity is as big a challenge as building quality"**. *Big in this case is use to compare if the size of the challenges are comparable.*

Whilst if you try to use creating equity is **as a big challenge as building quality** This begins to slide off course because the comparative sentence is incomplete.

However the whole format of the sentence is really not good English as I would suggest that you should not be comparing "Equity" and "Quality" and if you were then you would use "bigger" or "more challenging" [grammerly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives/) I would guess what you are trying to say is they are **"equally challenging"**

**getting all children off on the right foot is an often-stated goal of pre-K, but in many ways, creating equity is just as challenging as building quality.**

Ref [British council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/modifying-comparisons)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OP's construction [*{something} is as big a challenge as {something else}*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+as+big+a+challenge+as%22), nor is there any reason to suggest that ***as challenging*** is somehow "more appropriate" than ***as big a challenge*** here. Which form to use is simply a stylistic choice.

Comment: You are correct  they should have used **just** as big a challenge as building quality and I should have said just as challenging.

Comment: ***just*** is just an optional "intensifier" (though, curiously, my use of it in this very sentence is intended to ***downplay*** rather than ***intensify*** the importance of that grammatical class! :). And we can of course include that additional emphasis in both phrasings: *{something} is **just** as big a challenge as {something else}*.